Thread.join() behave strangely in Junit test case
I want to reproduce "ConcurrentModificationException". But it will work when manually run the program, while "not reproducing the exception" in Junit test case.
The behave-strange code is:
public class ConcurrentModificationExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Apple");
        list.add("Banana");
        list.add("Cherry");

        Runnable task = () -> {
            Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String fruit = iterator.next();
                if (fruit.equals("Banana")) {
                    list.remove(fruit); // Cause ConcurrentModificationException
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(task);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(task);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("List after remove banana：");
        for (String fruit : list) {
            System.out.println(fruit);
        }
    }
}

The test method is:
class ConcurrentModificationExampleTest {

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    void main() throws InterruptedException {
        ConcurrentModificationExample.main(new String[]{});
    }
}

While using CountDownLatch, the test can produce the exception as expected.
public class ConcurrentModificationExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Apple");
        list.add("Banana");
        list.add("Cherry");

        Runnable task = () -> {
            Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String fruit = iterator.next();
                if (fruit.equals("Banana")) {
                    list.remove(fruit); // Cause ConcurrentModificationException
                }
            }
            latch.countDown();
        };

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(task);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(task);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        latch.await();

        System.out.println("List after remove banana：");
        for (String fruit : list) {
            System.out.println(fruit);
        }
    }
}

My understanding is latch.await() has the similar function as thread1.join(); thread2.join(), then why they perform differently in Junit test case?

You cannot remove elements from a list while iterating (doing so invalidates the iterator). Try using iterator.remove() to remove the current element.

Yeah, I know removing elements from a multi-thread-non-safe list(e.g. ArrayList) while iterating will cause ConcurrentModificationException when running in multi-thread environment, the purpose of the program is exactly reproduce the exception. @dan1st

Note you may want to read this answer by rzwitserloot to a recent question. That question is about CMEs with a HashSet in an unsafe multi-threaded scenario, but parts of the answer may apply to your question as well.

A ConcurrentModificationException has nothing to do with threading, and in fact, if the collection is not thread-safe, it might not occur in cases where it might occur when doing both operations on the same thread. A ConcurrentModificationException happens when iterating over a collection (with a for-each or an iterator), while at the same time structurally modifying the collection (adding or removing items) without using that same iterator.

You've run into a JDK bug. One I filed, and which OpenJDK incorrectly denied.

// Cause ConcurrentModificationException


No, it will not.
That's an extraordinarily claim, so I will provide extraordinary evidence. Save to any text file, compile, and run:
import java.util.*;

class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Apple"); list.add("Banana"); list.add("Cherry");
                Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String fruit = iterator.next();
                        if (fruit.equals("Banana")) list.remove(fruit);
                }
        }
}

You'll find... no exception occurs.
The underlying issue is that hasNext() will happily return false even if concurrent modification has occurred; it's only next() that ends up checking the modification counter and throwing ConcurrentModificationException; if hasNext() (incorrectly) returns false, then next() is never called.
To run into this scenario, you need to do precisely what you do: You need to remove the second-to-last element. That is the only way to weave your way through such that no CoModEx is thrown.
As a mitigating factor, note that the j.u.Collection API spec indicates that ConcurrentModificationException is merely suggested; any implementation should put in 'best effort' to throw it, but does not need to guarantee it.
nevertheless, OpenJDK maintainer: This is a bug: Not checking in hasNext clearly fails the 'best effort' test. The 'best effort' comment was clearly intended to indicate that as an impl of some collection API, you are not obligated to make the modification checker concurrency-safe. Taking it to mean 'ah, whatever, throw CoModEx, dont throw it, who cares, spec says we do not have to, and this is faster' is ridiculous. After all, if that's the logic, why have a modification counter in the first place? Not having one is even faster.
All your further observations stem from this issue. It has nothing to do with JUnit, join(), or the interaction between junit and join().

And for the casual reader wondering why remove-last does throw CMEx: It throws via a roundabout way. hasNext() checks if the 'next-index' variable is equal to the current length of the underlying list, returning false if it is. Otherwise, it returns true, thus, next() is called. Add at end means the 'next-index' variable is one higher than current size, so true is returned. A roundabout way to get to the comodex. For the same reason, 'add one element in the final iterator' also produces comodex.

This is not a bug: "The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. " hasNext is allowed to return false because it already knows there are no further elements. While this behavior isn't guaranteed, the implementation is allowed to do that.

@dan1st It is a bug. "This behaviour is not guaranteed" either means [A] nobody cares and it isn't relevant, in which case it should be completely removed as it is faster, or [B] if it's cheap and easy to provide, it should be provided (i.e.: "Best effort"). This one is cheap and easy to provide, so it should. We're mincing words, the point is, the current behaviour is ridiculous. "May or may not" / "Depends on impl" is really bad; it should ONLY be used if you gain a lot in return. For e.g. the JMM's "without Happens Before, behaviour is undefined", you gain a ton. For this? Nil.

There are gains. As mentioned in the specification (Javadoc), this is only for detecting bugs and intentionally implementation-dependent. And the behavior of this implementation actually matches the behavior of what many people probably expect from hasNext: Not throwing an exception. And regarding best-effort, there are also other considerations that may be important (e.g. "the check should only be pnce per element in an enhanced for loop"/"hasNext should be as slmple as possible" (idk which ones are actually important for ArrayList).

Fail-Fast means it fails before any modified elements are actually accessed, not "as soon as we can possibly detect there is likely something wrong". You might not like this implementation but that's an opinion-based consideration and it doesn't violate the specification.

If a best effort implementation doesn't do what you'd like it to do, that is not a bug - especially if JDK maintainers don't consider it to be a bug.

This is an accidental phenomenon.
Example1 did not generate because Thread1 has already been executed.

Your answer seems more appropriate as a comment, in my opinion. Note that you should not post comments as answers just because you don't yet have the comment privilege. In any case, it's not clear (to me) what Example1 is referring to.
